# Get the URL users came from on an Error 404 Page using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I'm currently building an Error 404 page for a website project. People are redirected to this page using .htaccess if the page they requested can't be found.

I want to display on the custom Error page the URL or link that they came from, but I can't figure out how. I had a go at this:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
  $pageURL = 'http';
  if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
  $pageURL .= "://";
  if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL; // Finally, Returns the page URL
}
?>
```

And then I added the PHP function to my Error page:

```
The Page You Came From Was: <?php echo curPageURL(); ?>
```

Sadly, all this does in the end is display the URL of my Error page, and not the one where users were just redirected from.

Anyone have any ideas?

Adam.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

But it wont always be set.